# apachectl catch or suppress configtest's "Syntax OK"

Tags: bash, apache2

Apache's `configtest` is useful to catch syntax errors. On success it prints "Syntax OK" and when running `apachectl configtest` in a bash script I want to suppress this.

I have tried the usual output redirections to `/dev/null`, assigning the results to a variable like so:

```
AOUTPUT=$(/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -t && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl graceful)
```

but "Syntax OK" is always output.

Can this be suppressed?

Comment: It is probably writing to stderr, so try `apache2ctl -t 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @meuh thanks, that works. It also suppresses the message when there is a syntax error. Can you see a way to get the text into a variable, so I can match against it and choose what to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `$()` you can still redirect stderr to be the same as stdout, and then it will be captured by the assignment. For example:

```sh
if AOUTPUT=$(/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -t 2>&1)
then /usr/sbin/apache2ctl graceful
else rc=$?; printf "%s\n" "$AOUTPUT" >&2; exit $rc
fi
```

I added the `>&2` so the errors still come out on stderr, and the `exit` to try to duplicate the original error code from the command, but you would only really need them if you were putting this in a shell script and wanted to preserve those features.

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I need. I am using this in a shell script, and it's useful to have cron email me the errors and not the "Syntax OK" response